# Plotbands in the Highcharts .net wrapper do not show

Tags: .net, vb.net, highcharts

Hello I am very new to the site and still a novice at coding.

I am trying to create a basic line chart with a plotband in vb.net using the Highcharts .net wrapper, however the code I have written to create the plotband is not working but I converted it exactly as it should be *(at least I thinks so)* based on the Highcharts Demo.
**(The chart does display without the plotband)**

I have managed to create a line chart with a plotband based on the demo's using HTML5 and Javascript but not with VB.net.

I just want to know if I am missing something. Here is my progress so far:

```
    Dim chart As New Highcharts
    chart.Title.Text = "Eyecatching Title" '= New Title With {.Text = "title"}
    chart.Chart.Type = ChartType.Line

    chart.Subtitle.Text = "Mandatory subtitle"

    chart.YAxis.Add(New YAxis With {.Title = New YAxisTitle With {.Text = "Arbitrary Automated Number"}})

    chart.Legend.Layout = LegendLayout.Vertical
    chart.Legend.Align = LegendAlign.Right
    chart.Legend.VerticalAlign = LegendVerticalAlign.Middle

    chart.PlotOptions.Series.Label.ConnectorAllowed = False

    Dim xax As New XAxis With {.TickInterval = 1, .Min = 0, .Max = 9, .StartOnTick = False, .EndOnTick = False, .Type = XAxisType.Category}
    xax.Categories.Add("JAN")
    xax.Categories.Add("FEB")
    xax.Categories.Add("MAR")
    xax.Categories.Add("APR")
    xax.Categories.Add("MAY")
    xax.Categories.Add("JUN")
    xax.Categories.Add("JUL")
    xax.Categories.Add("AUG")
    xax.Categories.Add("SEP")
    xax.Categories.Add("OCT")
    xax.Categories.Add("NOV")
    xax.Categories.Add("DEC")

    chart.XAxis.Add(xax)
    chart.XAxis.Item(0) = xax

    Dim sd1 As New LineSeriesData With {.Y = 22} '.X = 1, 
    Dim sd2 As New LineSeriesData With {.Y = 33} '.X = 2, 
    Dim sd3 As New LineSeriesData With {.Y = 44} '.X = 3, 
    Dim sd4 As New LineSeriesData With {.Y = 55} '.X = 4, 
    Dim sd5 As New LineSeriesData With {.Y = 66} '.X = 5, 
    Dim sd6 As New LineSeriesData With {.Y = 33} '.X = 6, 
    Dim sd7 As New LineSeriesData With {.Y = 15} '.X = 7, 
    Dim sd8 As New LineSeriesData With {.Y = 99} '.X = 8, 
    Dim sd9 As New LineSeriesData With {.Y = 63} '.X = 9, 

    Dim s As New LineSeries With {.Name = "Installation"}
    s.Data.Add(sd1)
    s.Data.Add(sd2)
    s.Data.Add(sd3)
    s.Data.Add(sd4)
    s.Data.Add(sd5)
    s.Data.Add(sd6)
    s.Data.Add(sd7)
    s.Data.Add(sd8)
    s.Data.Add(sd9)
    chart.Series.Add(s)
    chart.Credits.Enabled = False

    Dim pb As New XAxisPlotBands With {.Color = "#F00", .From = "2", .To = "4"}

    xax.PlotBands.Add(pb)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make it work correctly, you need to initiate the `chart.XAxis` and `chart.XAxis.PlotBands` lists, before you will start adding their items. After that, you should be able to call `chart.XAxis.Add(xax)` and `xax.PlotBands.Add(pb)`.

```
var xax = new XAxis { TickInterval = 1, Min = 0, Max = 9, StartOnTick = false, EndOnTick = false, Type = XAxisType.Linear };
chart.XAxis = new List<XAxis> { xax };

var pbx = new XAxisPlotBands { Color = "#F00FFF", From = 2, To = 5, Label = new XAxisPlotBandsLabel { Text = "I'm plot band label" } };
xax.PlotBands = new List<XAxisPlotBands> { pbx };
```

I can send you working project through email or some hosting sevice if it will be helpful.

Kind regards!

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. I thought it would initialize all of the lists such as the xAxis.Plotbands when I create the chart variable, but thanks a lot Daniel!